# limit of integral of a continuous function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R $ be a function whose constraint $f[0,1] $ is a continuous function. check if the integral exists and if so calculate it.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{0}^{1}f(\frac{x^n}{1+x^2})dx$$.

How can I prove that it exists, just indicate that it is a continuous function in the constraint?
Another questio, to calculate the integral, do I integrate by part ( integratte $x^n$ e derivative $1/1+x^2)$?
Can you help me please?

Comment: Do you know the dominated convergence theorem? See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ define $f_n\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, $f_n(x)=f(\frac{x^n}{1+x^2})$. Then, by the continuity of $f$ the sequence $(f_n)$ converges pointwise to the function $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, $g(x)=f(0)$ for $x\in [0,1)$ and $g(1)=f(1/2)$. Now, you need some theorem, that allows you to interchange the limit and the integral:

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^1 f_n(x)dx\overset{?}=\int_{0}^1 \lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)dx=\int_{0}^1 g(x)dx=f(0)$.

The step with the question mark needs justification. Do you know a theorem that justifies this step?

Comment: Do you mean $f_n(x) := f(\frac{x^n}{1 + x^2})$?

Comment: Of course, thanks, I editted the answer.

Comment: I can justify by the dominated convergence theorem rigth?

Comment: Yes, as $f$ is continuous and $[0,1]$ is compact, f is bounded, and thus we have $|f_n(x)|\leq C$ for some  $C>0$ and all $x\in [0,1]$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Now one can apply the dominated convergence theorem with majorant $h\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}, h(x)=C$.